# How to get the filename of the current javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

In html, if I load an external javascript file like this

```
<script src="public/js/mycode.js"></script>
```

then in `mycode.js` file, is there some javascript function code I can call and it will return the string `"mycode.js"` or even `"public/js/mycode.js"`.

I don't want to hardcode any information about the script tag such as the filename.

Does anyone know a way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`document.currentScript` will return the currently executing script although I doubt older browsers support this.

```
Feature        Chrome   Firefox (Gecko)   Internet Explorer Opera   Safari
Basic support  29       4.0 (2.0)         Not supported     16      8
```

Unfortunately as usual IE is late to the game it looks like.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Comment: I think as long as its supported in IE11+ and relatively newer versions of firefox/chrome.

Comment: @omega it is entirely dependent on your implementation, but just in case you need to know the current support go here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Answer (score 0):

Use `onload` attribute at `script` tag ?

```html
<script onload="console.log(this.src)" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```